# C# open Form in Panel

Tags: c#, forms, panel

I have 3 forms. The Mainform, Form2 and Form3.

The Mainform contains a large panel in which Form 2 is displayed when the program is started.

I do that with the following code in my Mainform which works great:

```
   private Boolean loaded = false;
   private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!loaded)
        {
            openChildForm(new Form2());
            loaded = true;
        }
    }

 
    public Form activeForm = null;
    public void openChildForm(Form childForm)
    {
        if (activeForm != null)
        { 
            activeForm.Close();
        }

        activeForm = childForm;
        childForm.TopLevel = false;
        panelMain.Controls.Add(childForm);
        panelMain.Tag = childForm;
        childForm.BringToFront();
        childForm.Show();
    }
```

Now I want to add a button in Form2 (which is still being displayed in the Panel).
When I press that Button, Form2 should remove itself from the Mainform Panel and instead Form3 should be displayed in that MainForm panel. I tried that with the following code in Form2 at Buttonclick:

```
new Mainform().openChildForm(new Form3());
```

However, this does not work. It still displays the Form2 in the Panel and doesn't display Panel3.
In the Mainform it also says that "activeForm" is "null". I guess it is because of the "new MainForm()" call. Can I just access the MainForm without creating a new Instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I want to add a button in Form2 (which is still being displayed in
> the Panel). When I press that Button, Form2 should remove itself from
> the Mainform Panel and instead Form3 should be displayed in that
> MainForm panel.
>
> Can I just access the MainForm without creating a new Instance?

In Form2, you can cast the [ParentForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.parentform?view=netframework-4.7.2&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.ParentForm);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) property to `MainForm`, and then call `openChildForm()` against that:

```
// ... in Form2 ...
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainForm mf = this.ParentForm as MainForm;
    if (mf != null)
    {
        mf.openChildForm(new Form3());
    }
}
```